# I am working on array filters. i am stuck with adding filters to date

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, array-filter

I stored data in an array and I would like to make array filter with date parameter.

**Example:**

```
date.filter(obj => obj.date >= '2020-09-01 00:00:01 UTC' && obj.date <= '2020-09-05 23:59:59 UTC')
```

Then I need to see the record length between these dates, in above example, 5.

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
let orders = [
  {  amount: '100', user: 'admin', date: '2020-09-01 00:00:01 UTC' },
  {  amount: '120', user: 'admin', date: '2020-09-02 00:00:01 UTC' },
  {  amount: '80',  user: 'admin', date: '2020-09-03 00:00:01 UTC' },
  {  amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: '2020-09-04 00:00:01 UTC' },
  {  amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: '2020-09-05 00:00:01 UTC' },
  {  amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: '2020-09-06 00:00:01 UTC' },
  {  amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: '2020-09-07 00:00:01 UTC' },
  {  amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: '2020-09-08 00:00:01 UTC' },
  {  amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: '2020-09-09 00:00:01 UTC' },
  {  amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: '2020-09-10 00:00:01 UTC' },
  {  amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: '2020-09-11 00:00:01 UTC' },
];

console.log(orders)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those **aren’t** dates. Those are **string literals**. You’ll need to *parse* the date string into an actual date before you can do any calculations with it.

Comment: This works fine; it just needs to be `orders.filter`, not `date.filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the date strings into actual [Date objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```js
const orders = [
  {  amount: '100', user: 'admin', date: '2020-09-01 00:00:01 UTC' },
  {  amount: '120', user: 'admin', date: '2020-09-02 00:00:01 UTC' },
  {  amount: '80',  user: 'admin', date: '2020-09-03 00:00:01 UTC' },
  {  amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: '2020-09-04 00:00:01 UTC' },
  {  amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: '2020-09-05 00:00:01 UTC' },
  {  amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: '2020-09-06 00:00:01 UTC' },
  {  amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: '2020-09-07 00:00:01 UTC' },
  {  amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: '2020-09-08 00:00:01 UTC' },
  {  amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: '2020-09-09 00:00:01 UTC' },
  {  amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: '2020-09-10 00:00:01 UTC' },
  {  amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: '2020-09-11 00:00:01 UTC' },
];

const getOrdersBetween = (orders, start, end) => orders.filter(({ date }) => new Date(date) >= new Date(start) && new Date(date) <= new Date(end));

const result = getOrdersBetween(orders, '2020-09-01 00:00:01 UTC', '2020-09-05 23:59:59 UTC');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This returns an empty array and with data provided, the array must have 5 elements...

Comment: The date strings are not in a format that can be parsed reliably by `new Date`, so all of these will result in a comparison against _Invalid Date_, which is `NaN`, numerically; the comparison will always fail, so the result will be empty. Since these are still derived from [ISO 8601](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), they _can_ be ordered lexicographically as strings. Converting the strings to Dates is superfluous. The only thing wrong with the question is the mismatching variable name.